# Problems using DateAdd function

Tags: ms-access

I'm super new to Access and need to develop a form linked to an SQL database for people to search info without having to use SQL. The database is basically a number code representing an occurence, and each of these numbers are linked to a whole range of dates: the start date, the end date, etc. What I want to do is use a text box for the person to select a start date and then a combo box to add days to this date selected. For example: the person chooses Feb 3th 2019 on the text box and "7" on the combo box, meaning he/she wants all the entries with a start date between Feb 3th and Feb 10th.

I managed to make it work using 2 text boxes with date selectors,  but I need the combo box to limit the days used in the query to 7, otherwise Access crashes due to time limit to reach the linked database. This is the query I'm currently using on the SQL view mode of Access queries (my version of Access is in Portuguese, sorry).

```
SELECT dbo_temp_aof_reativos_ferramenta.area, dbo_temp_aof_reativos_ferramenta.data_abertura, dbo_temp_aof_reativos_ferramenta.data_termino, CStr(dbo_temp_aof_reativos_ferramenta.ia) AS ia, dbo_temp_aof_reativos_ferramenta.data_est_termino, dbo_temp_aof_reativos_ferramenta.data_atuacao, dbo_temp_aof_reativos_ferramenta.atividade, dbo_temp_aof_reativos_ferramenta.ocorrencia, dbo_temp_aof_reativos_ferramenta.fase, dbo_temp_aof_reativos_ferramenta.org, dbo_temp_aof_reativos_ferramenta.chpras, dbo_temp_aof_reativos_ferramenta.conta_cartao, dbo_temp_aof_reativos_ferramenta.cartao, dbo_temp_aof_reativos_ferramenta.jornada, dbo_temp_aof_reativos_ferramenta.tipo2, dbo_temp_aof_reativos_ferramenta.subjornada, dbo_temp_aof_reativos_ferramenta.assunto INTO dados_export
FROM dbo_temp_aof_reativos_ferramenta
WHERE (((dbo_temp_aof_reativos_ferramenta.area)=Forms!Indicadores!Area) 
And ((dbo_temp_aof_reativos_ferramenta.data_abertura) Between Forms!Indicadores!DATAIN And DateAdd('d',Forms!Indicadores!DATATER,'DATAIN')))
```

Datater is the combo box with the number of days and Datain is the text box with the selected start date. I'm gonna attach the form so you can all see how it looks.

Can anyone help me, please? =)

Comment: Exactly what is the error? Don't put **DATAIN** within apostrophes. Use `Forms!Indicadores!DATAIN`.

Comment: @June7 I've tried that too, but it didn't work. It seems like it is ignoring the condition, because it simply returns an empty table .

Comment: Must exit textbox or combobox before running the query. Are you clicking a button to open query or form or report bound to query? Query works for me. I don't use dynamic parameterized queries. I prefer VBA to build filter criteria and apply to form or report when opening.

Answer (score 0):

It should work, but you may have to specify `Forms!Indicadores!DATAIN` And `Forms!Indicadores!DATATER` as *parameters* of data type *DateTime* and *Integer* respectively.